# problems with InAppBrowser on dynamic links

Tags: jquery, cordova

I have this code in start.html of my phonegap build app.

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
                                  try {


                                  function appBrowser(url) {

                                    var ref = window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
                                    ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function() { alert('start: ' + event.url); });
                                    ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() { alert('stop: ' + event.url); });
                                    ref.addEventListener('exit', function() { alert(event.type); });

                                }


                                  } catch (e) {

                                    alert(e);

                                  }


                                  }, false);
```

If I just statically put this html below, everything works fine.

```
<a href="" onClick="javascript:appBrowse('http://www.link.se')">Link</a>
```

I then try to add the link dynamically to a div on the sama page (with class link), with this, called from js/index.js.

```
$('.link').append("<a href='' onClick='appBrowser("+ encodeURI(link) + ")'>Test</a>");
```

The link gets added, but when I click the link I get following error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :                   start.html:1

Any ideas? I'm using jquery mobile as my front end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you bind a click event on those specific links by their class instead of using onclick?

```
$('body').on('click', '.appBrowser', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');

    window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
});
```

Give the links which will be opened with inAppBrowser the class `appBrowser`, and they'll be opened using inAppBrowser.

Answer (score 0):

Add like this syntax:

```
$('.link').append("<a href=\"\" onClick=\"appBrowser(encodeURI(link))\">Test<\/a>");
```